# How to validate pattern AB12CD

Tags: regex

The requirement is "each 2 digits must be only numbers or only text" - so valid patterns are AB-12-CD or 12-AB-CD or AB-CD-12, 12-34-AB.

The below suggested pattern working fine without hyphen but if we want to add a hyphen in between, how to do?
\b(?=[A-Z\d]*[A-Z])(?=[A-Z\d]*\d)(?:[A-Z]{2}|\d{2})+\b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeat 1 or more times matching either 2 uppercase chars or 2 digits. Note that there are no hyphens present in the example data.

```
\b(?:[A-Z]{2}|\d{2})+\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JMVzXn/1)

If there must be a digit and an uppercase character present, you could also use a positive lookahead:

```
\b(?=[A-Z\d]*[A-Z])(?=[A-Z\d]*\d)(?:[A-Z]{2}|\d{2})+\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GOocjN/1)

Comment: any idea how to validate with hypen AB-12-CD or 12-AB-CD or AB-CD-12, 12-34-AB

Comment: @gvpeela Like this? https://regex101.com/r/xvnFq5/1